# Xcode RSS Images

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app that I am developing in Xcode which retrieves a RSS feed from my site and puts it into a table. Recently, I have created a new homepage with a featured article at the top, and I want to be able to have the image from the articles shown with it. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: @shaikriyaz this has nothing to do with `xcode IDE` please don't retag with it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that in the RSS Feed there is a key called image or similar which its value will be an address pointing to the image.
After you load the article you should download each image asynchronously. For this I'd suggest you use [NSOperation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSOperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html).

There is a tutorial in [Ray Wenderlich website](http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues) which shows how to accomplish this.

You could use some kind of cache to avoid the images downloading each time.